# Got replacement note 2, and gmail did not back up my apps, contacts, nothing? Why not?

Tags: backup

Just like it says in the Title i got a new phone and added my existing gmail account that i know is backed up already because I have been there and done that 10 times already.(hence why I got a replacement phone...well part of the ROGERS story)
 Anyways nothing synced, downloaded, nada, zip, zilch!

Any ideas..?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Google Backup: Multiple devices using the same account - what happens on Restore?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42245/16575) -- where more of us are wondering about how this "Google backup" is supposed to work...